# GC overhead limit exceeded in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After some update of Android Studio I can't build signed APK because it fails with "GC overhead limit exceeded". I tried to add

> dexOptions {
>           javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
>   }

but it doesn't help. Any other options to how fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` in gradle.properties?